# Team Expected Points Given Very Limited Information

Tags: probability, bayesian, random-variable, expected-value

Suppose we were interested in projecting Team A's expected points in a given game. Lets say, on average over a very large sample size, they score 3 points a game against an average team. Then lets say that Team B allows 2 points a game against an average team. Finally, we will say that the average team scores and allows 2.5 points per game. If this was the only information given, and all of the factors for this game are average (No Hot Streaks Occurring, Average amount of Injuries, Playing on neutral territory (No Home/Away Advantage), etc.), how would we predict how many points Team A will score? Obviously this would be in the range (2,3).

Comment: Sports results are highly unpredictable.  You mentioned the key factors. Injuries are always critical.

Comment: edited :) I understand sports are very hard to predict, but suppose you had to make a statistical guess based on this information.